# Can I Get A List Of Keys In An entrySet In Java Without Using Generics?

Tags: java, generics, jmeter, beanshell

I'm using BeanShell in JMeter. BeanShell is a Java interpreter that does not support generics. As soon as I enter an angle bracket (e.g. "<") my script will be rejected.

If I could use generics I would do the following:

```
for ( Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : vars.entrySet() ) {
    System.out.println( "  key = " + entry.getKey() );
}
```

However I cannot create the variable entry because I'm not permitted to declare `Map.Entry<String,Object>` in my script.

So - given my method `entrySet()` and the type it returns of `Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>>` is there any way I can get a list of (or iterate over) the keys in this set without explicitly referring to a generic type?

e.g. something like:

```
for ( String keys : vars.entrySet().somethingMagic() ) {
    System.out.println( "  key = " + key );
}
```

Comment: I'll simply uninstall the interpreter which does not support the feature that was added way back in Java 5. Or at least update it.

Comment: @Rohit Jain - I'm really looking for an answer from a Java expert that knows more about the language than I.

Comment: Have you tried just calling it without any generic brackets? That should work..

Comment: @Kristoffer E - thank you, you were the first with the correct answer. I tried this and it worked. The answer I've accepted is the one closest to yours in the answer set.

Comment: Anything that can be written using generics can be written equivalently using no generics (it's called type erasure -- it's what the compiler kind of does anyway) by removing the generics and inserting appropriate casts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try either:

```
for ( Map.Entry entry : vars.entrySet() ) {
    System.out.println( "  key = " + entry.getKey() );
}
```

Or:

```
for ( String keys : vars.keySet()) {
    System.out.println( "  key = " + key );
}
```

Comment: You little beauty! This worked (so long as I imported the namespace of java.util.Map first or referred to it as java.util.Map.Entry).

Comment: Actually, you can get rid of all types in Beanshell, i.e. `for ( entry : vars.entrySet() ) {` or `for ( keys : vars.keySet()) {`. In this case you need no imports.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming vars is a Map, you can call `vars.keySet()`.

Comment: Thanks - I guessed this, too, but vars is not a Map - it is a class of JMeterVariables which does not expose this function.

Comment: You might clarify in your question that `vars` is a `JMeterVariables` object. In any case, the first answer by @Puce should do it. You may see a compile warning, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your original code without generics:

```
for ( Map.Entry entry : vars.entrySet() ) {
    System.out.println( "  key = " + entry.getKey() );
}
```

Will probably give you a warning, but should still work

Answer (score 0):

Use jsr223 + groovy in external file .
This is better for:

- performance
- being up to date (you can use JAVA 6 syntax)

...

In upcoming 2.9 , you will be able to have caching by putting it in text area:

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-dev/201301.mbox/%3CCAH9fUpa_BWtcQDg3etUE5OuVj_QeOC0YdenkqTFhurxp%2B2P9MQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E